# What are Client side Development options in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, jsom

I have only SharePoint designer and SharePoint site, neither we have a visual studio nor access to central administration site so no chance of server side code development.
Now I want to know that what are the development options that I have in this environment?

Will JSOM work here? if yes then How using content editor web part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the JavaScript client object model (JSOM) in Sharepoint 2010.

- It is useful in scenarios where data needs to access and manipulated after the page has been loaded.
- It provides an asynchronous way of displaying data on your Web Parts and Web Pages.
- It is simple to use and can be loaded even from within an editor similar to the `content editor Web Part` as the following:

  - Upload the Js file script to a SharePoint library to your site.
  - Get the Full URL of the uploaded file.
  - Open the page that you need to run your Js script.
  - From site Action > Edit this Page.

[image]

- From the above ribbon > Add  a web part.

[image]

- At Content and Media category > Select Content Edito > Click Add button.

[image]

- Edit Web Part.

[image]

- Add the js file URL in Content Link section

[image]

- Check In, Save and Close.
- the Jsom Script now is attached to your page via Content Editor and should be working properly.

---

Check some JSOM examples in SharePoint 2010 at

- [Working with the ECMAScript Client Object Model (JSOM) in SharePoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh372944%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#odc_spe14_ta_WorkwithJSOM_Conclusion)
- [How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items Using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Working with the ECMAScript Client Object Model (JSOM) in SharePoint 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2011/07/13/working-with-the-ecmascript-client-object-model-jsom-in-sharepoint-2010part-1-nikhil-sachdeva/)

Comment: Thank You very much M.Qassas, I appreciate ur quick answer